# Creating a json array with jsonify

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am trying to create a json array using jsonify. Something like

```
{[
    {
       "a":4,
       "b":5
    },
    {
       "a":4,
       "b":5
    }
 ]}
```

except on a larger scale. I am currently trying something like this:

```
jsonArr=[]
for i in list:
    jsonArr.append(jsonify(dict(a=4,b=5)))
return jsonArr
```

but this throws `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`
What should I do? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not valid JSON. JSON objects are key-value pair entities. In your case, you are creating an object with just an array in it.

Comment: @thefourtheye How could I store information in a similar format in valid json?

Comment: @dejavo That does not work. It simply throws a list index out of range error.

Comment: @dejavo I'm not sure what you mean. Something like `jsonArr.append(push(dict(a=4,b=5)))`?

Comment: @DeJaVo: This is a Python question... there is no `push` method on any of the objects involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask's `jsonify` does not support top-level objects other than dictionaries (*objects* in JSON). This is because in the past there were some security issues with top-level arrays.

This behavior has been changed in the latest Flask master, but simply use `json.dumps` to serialize your list. Also, you should only call it *once* on the final object - not on the actual list elements.

```
>>> import json
>>> list_ = [{'a': 4, 'b': 5}, {'a': 6, 'b': 7}]
>>> print json.dumps(list_)
[{"a": 4, "b": 5}, {"a": 6, "b": 7}]
```